# Using Static Member Function to Access Static Data Member

Tags: c++, class, static, static-members, private-members

I am trying to access a static data member using a static member function, so that I may call this function and retrieve the data member. The goal is to increase/decrease this static data member to count how many objects are existing in the program.

Verbatim from assignment:

> A static member function called getNumObjects should be provided that takes no parameters and returns an int indicating the number of objects of type Complex currently in existence.

My code so far:

Complex.hpp

```
class Complex{
public:
...
// Get the number of complex objects in the current program
        static int& getNumObjects();
...

private:
...
        static int counter; // static counter
...
}
```

Complex.cpp

```
// Initialize object counter for getNumObjects()
int Complex::counter = 0;
// Get number of objects existing in the current program
static int& Complex::getNumObjects(){
        return counter;
}
```

testComplex.cpp

```
// checks to see how many complex objects are open currently
        std::cout << "How many complex objecst are in existence? ";
        int num = Complex::getNumObjects();
        std::cout << num << '\n';
        std::cout << "successful\n";
```

I don't understand why the compiler keeps throwing me this error:

```
 error: cannot declare member function ‘static int& Complex::getNumObjects()’ to have static linkage [-fpermissive]
 static int& Complex::getNumObjects(){
```

or this error:

```
In function ‘int getNumObjects()’:
/../../../ error: ‘counter’ was not declared in this scope
  return counter;
         ^~~~~~~
/../../../ note: suggested alternative: ‘toupper’
  return counter;
         ^~~~~~~
         toupper
```

I've searched far and wide, I seem to have initialized my private data member just fine as well as the function. getNumObjects() is stated as a class, so why is it saying the scope of the function isn't right?

Comment: Why exactly are you returning a reference to `int`?

Comment: @KinanAlSarmini In a similar fashion, I have other functions which retrieve other private data members, which is why I thought I should just use a reference to try and access the counter

Comment: A better idea would be to increase / decrease the counter internally in the constructor / destructor instead of returning a reference and updating externally.

Comment: @KinanAlSarmini My constructor and deconstructor have internal counters, however a second question arises. Does the move constructor and copy constructor mean a new object was created?

Comment: Any constructor invocation means that a new object was created. A move constructor doesn't really say anything about the lifetime of the object being constructed, it's more about the lifetime of the object being constructed from. So I would say you should increase the counter in any constructor you might have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand why the compiler keeps throwing me this error:

Because you repeated `static` in the member function definition. The function is already declared `static`; C++ syntax requires you to omit `static` in the cpp file:

```
int Complex::counter = 0;
// Get number of objects existing in the current program
int& Complex::getNumObjects(){
    return counter;
}
```

**Note:** It is probably not a good idea to return `int&`, because the callers would be able to modify `counter` without your knowledge:

```
Complex::getNumObjects() = -123; // <<== returning reference makes this legal
```

This is very bad, because it completely breaks encapsulation. Essentially, your `counter` ends up being exposed as if it were a public member variable.

You should change your function to return `int` instead:

```
int Complex::getNumObjects(){
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation! I really wasn't sure if I had to call static again in my cpp file and +1 for the extra knowledge about returning `int&`.

Answer (score 1):

The `static` keyword should be used in the `class` declaration only. The method implementation should omit the `static` declaration:

```
int& Complex::getNumObjects(){
        return counter;
}
```

Oddly, you have already followed this rule for your static member variable ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You definitely must keep track of the objects in the destructor and constructor. Also, you really want your counter to a `atomic` so that no race condition occurs when running on multiple threads.

```
struct Complex
{
  Complex()
  { ++counter; }

  Complex(Complex const&other)
  : _real(other._real), _imag(other._imag)
  { ++counter; }

  Complex(double r, double i=0)
  : _real(r), _imag(i)
  { ++counter; }

  // and so on for all other constructors

  Complex&operator=(Complex const&) = default;

  Complex&operator=(double x)
  {
    _real = x;
    _imag = 0;
    return *this;
  }

 ~Complex() { --counter; }

  static int getNumObjects() { return counter; }

private:
  double _real,_imag;
  static std::atomic<int> counter;
};
```

There is not really the need for a move constructor (since no data on the heap are managed by `Complex`).